# Operation that returns unique values when applied to numbers from a set

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

According to the Fundamental theorem of arithmetic every number can be written as the product of prime numbers other than 1 and this product is unique (not taking into account factors order).
On top of that if a prime number $p$ is a factor for a given number $b$ then $b \pmod p = 0$

I'm giving this extremely simplified explanation because it is just loosely related to my question.
What i want to know is if there's another set of numbers that given an operation it will have these 2 properties you can find in the fundamental theorem. That is:

1) The operation on any quantity of numbers from the set must result in a unique number
2) it is relatively trivial to know if a number from the set was used in the operation

And, unlike the product of primes, it must not grow up that much (let's say that, unlike the product of the first 1000 primes, the operation on the first 1000 numbers of the set should be "little" enough to be contained into a 64bit long Java variable)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for too much. Consider the following. Let $S$ be the set of 1000 smallest numbers in this hypothetical set. The operation must assign to each subset $R\subseteq S$ a unique number, call it $f(R)$. Because there are $2^{1000}$ subsets of $S$ we must have $2^{1000}$ distinct values for $f(R)$.

If all the values $f(R)$ are non-negative integers then necessarily some (=most) of them will have at least $1000$ bits, far outside the range of Java long.

---

The **best** you can do is to have $S$ consist of powers of two, and let the operation be bitwise XOR (or addition, for this set $S$ it makes no difference). You can then check from $f(R)$ whether a given bit is ON to test whether the corresponding number participated in the process.

Answer (score 1):

For the first requirement it sounds like you are looking for a perfect hash function.  A perfect hash function will map a set (which may be the integers or the natural numbers) onto a set of integers without collision.